# How to make a checkbox group behave like a radio button group in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to make checkboxes that have been rendered via a loop behave like radio buttons. I do not want to use radio buttons and make them look like checkboxes. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what you tried doing and what's the issue and we can help. Asking for ready made code is not the role of SO. In your case considerer multiple state in one or various useState and a function that triggers one and untriggers the other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.